# I cannot open a new project WebStorm React

Tags: reactjs, npm, webstorm

I cannot open a new project at the WebStorm React JS.

- WebStorm v 2020.3.2
- Node v 15.0.1

I am starting a new project and I got this error.

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js" --yes create-react-app .

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\projects\todo-new/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\projects\todo-
new\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\ivanh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-08T18_52_52_706Z-debug.log

Done
```

Comment: can you post your package.json?

Comment: package.json is not created

Comment: you see my answer on the space in the file name below?

Comment: also, its looking for a package.json, you need to create one. in my answer below i outline this. good luck!

Comment: package.json
{
  "name": "todo-new",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. maybe it will help someone.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g npm@latest
```

deleted folder node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that there is a space in your file name

```
no such file or directory, open 'C:\projects\todo- new\package.json'
```

if you look between `todo-` and `new` there is a space.

If you dont have a package.json file, run `npm init` to create one

Comment: there is no space here. I jast  created package.jason to  using npm init. 

{
  "name": "todo-new",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: other weird thing is that your error shows a path with a forward slash... "C:\projects\todo-new/package.json"

Comment: I also noticed this. but I do not write the path it makes the program automatically

Comment: I can run npx create-react-app my-app and it will works. But this is not a solution.

Comment: why isnt that a solution. I don't know webstorm very well, but doesnt it just run create-react-app? It seems like a webstorm problem.

Comment: and what is a result of running `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js" --yes create-react-app .` in terminal in a new folder?